# Swift - ReloadData doesn't call CellForRowatIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm kind of a swift noobie trying to load my JSON data from my server into my UITableView, but when I call the ReloadData method nothing seems to happen (while it should be calling CellForRowatIndexPath as far as I know). I've tried some solutions that I found (like putting it in the main thread), but those didn't do the trick. So I wonder if anyone could help me with this, because I don't know what to do.

Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

private let reuseIdentifier = "PresenceCell"

class PresenceController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var presenceTableView: UITableView!
    var presenceList = [] as [Presence]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addPresence))
        loadPresences(date: NSDate() as Date)


        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return presenceList.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PresenceCell
        let presence = presenceList[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblPresenceName.text = presence.name
        cell.lblPresenceTimes.text = presence.times
        if (presence.reasons.characters.contains("S")) {
            cell.lblPresenceSTD.isHidden = true
        } else {
            cell.lblPresenceSTD.isHidden = false
        }
        if (presence.reasons.characters.contains("M")) {
            cell.lblPresenceMDN.isHidden = true
        } else {
            cell.lblPresenceMDN.isHidden = false
        }
        if (presence.reasons.characters.contains("C")) {
            cell.lblPresenceEDH.isHidden = true
        } else {
            cell.lblPresenceEDH.isHidden = false
        }
        if (presence.reasons.characters.contains("L")) {
            cell.lblPresenceLEA.isHidden = true
        } else {
            cell.lblPresenceLEA.isHidden = false
        }
        if (presence.reasons.characters.contains("T")) {
            cell.lblPresenceTRD.isHidden = true
        } else {
            cell.lblPresenceTRD.isHidden = false
        }
        if (presence.event) {
            cell.swPresenceEvent.isOn = true
        } else {
            cell.swPresenceEvent.isOn = false
        }
        return cell
    }

    func addPresence(){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addPresenceSegue", sender: self)
    }

    private func loadPresences(date: Date) {
        let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
        dateFormat.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        let dateString = dateFormat.string(from: date)
        let url = "MyUrl" + dateString
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).responseJSON{ response in
            if let json = response.result.value {
                let dictionary = json as! [String:Any]
                let presences = dictionary["presences"] as! NSArray
                for index in 0..<presences.count {
                    let jsonPresence = presences[index] as! [String:Any]
                    let presence = Presence(id: jsonPresence["id"] as! Int, name: jsonPresence["name"] as! String, times: (jsonPresence["starttime"] as! String) + " - " + (jsonPresence["endtime"] as! String), reasons: jsonPresence["reasons"] as! String, event: ((jsonPresence["event"] as! Int) == 1))
                    //add your data into tables array from textField
                    self.presenceList.append(presence)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `DispatchQueue.main.async` around the `reloadData` call?

Comment: @nathan yes, but there is no difference

Comment: Are you setting the data source of the table view? Is the frame of the table view 0x0?

Comment: @DennisvanOpstal You're calling reload data in the right place at least. Good job! (A lot of beginners have trouble understanding asynchronicity.) Have you tried printing out your json? And also have you set your table view's data source and delegate in the interface?

Comment: @nathan the delegate and datasource are set in the storyboard, also I can see the rows my uitableview (but there is no content), so I believe it is fullscreen and not 0x0

Comment: @LyndseyScott I printed out my JSON and the JSON was right (I also put the values in a Presence object and that works too), the datasource and delegate are set in the storyboard

Comment: Make sure presenceList isn't empty. If numberOfRowsInSection return 0 CellForRowatIndexPath will never be called.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ I debugged and at the moment before calling ReloadData it has 1 entry (as it should have)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your numberOfRowsInSection method isn't quite right. Try this:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return presenceList.count
    }
```

Comment: Awesome. Good luck!